# Filtering Images from API array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to retrieve only the image media types from this API call. The code I have written is returning an empty array. I know it's an error in the filter but I can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas?

Data from API:
[image: Data from API]

empty array being returned from the code I have written:
[image: empty array being returned from the code I have written]

```js
import axios from 'axios';


const getImages = (query) => {
    if(!query) {
        return Promise.resolve([])
    } else {
        return axios
          .get(`https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=${query}`)
          .then((response) => {
              console.log(response.data.collection.items)
        let imageResults = response.data.collection.items
        let parsedImages = imageResults.filter(i => imageResults[0].media_type === "image")
        console.log(parsedImages)
        return parsedImages
                  })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
}

export default getImages;
```

Comment: you should be using `i[0].media_type` not `imageResults[0].media_type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get the right property.
`media_type` is on `response.data.collection.items[_].data[_].media_type`

Here is a valid filter :

```
let images = data.collection.items.filter(i => i.data.filter(d => d.media_type == 'image').length > 0)
```